# Loop will not break

Tags: python, list, while-loop, break

I'm creating a sort of database, using a list that is read in from the user. When the user enters `finish` I want the while loop to stop. However, for some reason I need to enter `finish` TWICE for it to break the loop.

Also, the list is empty after being returned.

```
def readNames():
nameList = []
count = 0
while count != -1: #infinite loop
    addList = raw_input("Please enter a name: ")
    if addList == 'finish':
        return nameList
        break
    nameList.append(addList)
    print nameList
```

I'm invoking it and checking if it worked with

```
readNames()
print readNames()
```

Also, here is the output

```
Please enter a name: Dave
['Dave']
Please enter a name: Gavin
['Dave', 'Gavin']
Please enter a name: Paul
['Dave', 'Gavin', 'Paul']
Please enter a name: Test1
['Dave', 'Gavin', 'Paul', 'Test1']
Please enter a name: finish
Please enter a name: finish
[]
>>>
```

Comment: Works fine for me (in IDLE). Apart from that, there are much easier ways to make an infinite loop (`while True:` is sufficient; why create a bogus variable + condition? I was actually looking for the `count = -1`...). Also, the `break` is unneeded (`return` exits the function and therefore the loop).

Comment: Works fine for me, some notes though: You can simply do `while True:` for your infinite loop, you also don't need to `break` after you returned as the `break` will never be reached. `names = readNames()` works just fine for me. PS: I've fixed your indentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do

```
readNames()
print readNames()
```

you run the function **twice**. On the 2nd run you just enter "finish" and thats why your list remains empty.

What you want to do is this:

```
def readNames():
    nameList = []
    while True: #infinite loop
        addList = raw_input("Please enter a name: ")
        if addList == 'finish':
            return nameList
        nameList.append(addList)

# store the result, then print it
names = readNames()
print names
```

Comment: Thanks for the massive help. Been stuck on this for ages. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think your calling code is accidentally invoking `readnames()` twice.

Comment: Yes, it appears that is what is happening. After removing `print readNames()`, it is breaking as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, after you posted your code, I can see the issue:

```
readNames()
print readNames()
```

You call `readNames`, read those names from stdin as planned, properly `return` the read names **and then throw the result away** because you don't assign it to anything (`names = readNames()`). Then you call `readNames` **again**, and it appears to you as if it didn't exit the loop (it did, but you told it to loop again). You type `finish` again, and the second invocation of `readNames` ends without any names entered (`nameList` is a local variable, so it is lost after the function execution ends), so you get back `[]`.

To fix this, (1) brush up your general programming knowledge ;) and (2) do something like `names = readNames()`; `print names`.

Comment: Many thanks for the help, unfortunately THC4k beat you to it. :)

Answer (score -1):

Could you not replace

```
if addList == 'finish':
        return nameList
        break
```

With

```
if addList == 'finish':
        return nameList
        count = -1
```

?

James

Comment: -1 Not only this is still superfluous (see the comments by me and Ivo), it also doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Just adding my two cents. Sorry people.